Relative "what" refers to a specific referent, not a kind?
The sentence (1a) is ambiguous, as it seems to allow both the interpretation in (1b), where what you ate and what I ordered refer to the same referent, and the interpretation in (1c), where the second what refers to the same kind. Here, I assume this reading of (1c) is just coerced by the situation, that is, a pragmatic interpretation, and that the basic meaning of what in what I ordered is a specific entity, not a kind.
(1)
a. What you ate is what I ordered.
b. The food that you ate is the food that I ordered. (the same referent, e.g., You ate my pasta.)
c. The food that you ate is the same kind of food that I ordered. (the same kind, e.g., I also ate pasta.)
Therefore, what I ordered in (2a) is mostly interpreted as that particular food that I ordered even though both readings may be possible. On the other hand, what you ate in (2b) is interpreted as the kind or type of the food you ate because the fact that it is impossible to order the particular food that someone ate coerces the kind reading.
(2)
a. You ate what I ordered.    (referential reading)
b. I ordered what you ate.    (coerced kind reading)
If we want to convey the kind reading, we use the same one instead of what as in (3).
(3)
a. You ate the same one I ordered.
b. I ordered the same one you ate.
What do you think? Do you agree with my assumption that what used in free relatives basically refers to a specific thing, not a kind?

Ambiguity (especially with regard to reference) is all around us. You see someone reading a book and you say "I read that book." You could mean that title or that copy. "That's my book" can refer to ownership or authorship. It's a source of jokes: "I have Graves' disease and he has mine." We get more bang for our buck if we can rely on context to disambiguate.

Maybe this belongs on Philosophy or Linguistics SE, I don't see how it relates specifically to the English language. But stuff is ambiguous, that's life.

A sentence set up for double meanings tends to have double meanings.

Related is the ambiguity of the picture noun 'painting' say: "That is my painting" ... (1) of me? (2) by me? and/or (3) owned by me? Leaving aside (4) the one I like above all others .... (cf "He's my kind of guy").
